# Aggregate sum of rows identified by max value

Tags: sql

I am trying to aggregate a the max value of each type, then sum all of this to one value:

| resource_id | price |
| --- | --- |
| a | 100 |
| a | 84 |
| b | 33 |
| b | 100 |

A 100 and B 100 would be selected (max value of each type of A and B).

Expected return:

```
200
```

What I have so far:

```
SELECT   resource_id, MAX(price)
FROM     costs
GROUP BY resource_id
```

It is currently returning A = 100 and B = 100... just need a little help on how to sum all this into a return of just 200

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your query...

```
    select sum(m_price)
    from (
        SELECT   resource_id, MAX(price) as m_price
        FROM     costs
        GROUP BY resource_id
        )z
```